# BLE major and minor not updating

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I'm using AmebaD RTL8722DM mini similar to arduino to make it a ibeacon using its libraries on examples. I want to update major and minor values but i get 0 on both. Can't understand what is wrong with it, like in the picture below.
[nrf connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PtbQ.jpg)

Below the example code im running:

```
#include "BLEDevice.h"
#include "BLEBeacon.h"

iBeacon beacon;
//altBeacon beacon;

// See the following for generating UUIDs:
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/
#define UUID "00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF"
 int a = 123;
 int b = 456;


void setup() {
    // For all possible BLE manufacturer IDs, refer to:
    // www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers/
    beacon.setManufacturerId(0x004C); // MfgId (0x004C: Apple Inc)
    beacon.setRSSI(0xBF);             // rssi: (0xBF: -65 dBm)
    beacon.setMajor(a);          // 123
    beacon.setMinor(b);          // 456
    beacon.setUUID(UUID);

    BLE.init();
    BLE.configAdvert()->setAdvType(GAP_ADTYPE_ADV_NONCONN_IND);
    BLE.configAdvert()->setAdvData(beacon.getAdvData(), beacon.advDataSize);
    BLE.configAdvert()->setScanRspData(beacon.getScanRsp(), beacon.scanRspSize);
    BLE.beginPeripheral();


}

void loop() {

  a = a + 1;
  b = b + 1;


    delay(1000);
    
}
```

Comment: Where does the definition of `iBeacon` come from?  Is it in `#include "BLEBeacon.h"`?  Where do we see that?

Comment: It is from 'BLEBeacon.h' i guess

Comment: Right, my point is that what library or SDK does `BLEBeacon.h` come from?   In order for us to help you we need to know the toolset you are using.   This is not a standard C header file.  Please provide a link to the documentation or toolset that told you to use BLEBeacon.h

Comment: I'm using this example [Amebad BLE beacon](https://www.amebaiot.com/en/amebad-arduino-ble-beacon/) a package that can be installed on arduino ide. Acctually here is the library [Amebad libraries github](https://github.com/ambiot/ambd_arduino/tree/master/Arduino_package/hardware/libraries/BLE/src)

Comment: See my answer with suggestions on how to use the sample code vin the repository you mention to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The methods `beacon.setMajor(a);` and `beacon.setMinor(b);` take a `uint16_t` but the code shown passes in a parameter of `int`, which is probably a signed 32-bit integer.  Because the library does binary manipulation of the values after calling on those methods, it may be mangling the values when passed in as larger integers.

Short answer:  Declare your major and minor as `uint16_t`.

If this still doesn't help, try copying the sample code exactly from here: https://github.com/ambiot/ambd_arduino/blob/master/Arduino_package/hardware/libraries/BLE/examples/BLEBeacon/BLEBeacon.ino

When you run that sample, do you see major 123, minor 456 in the scanner app?  If so, modify the code one step at a time and retest between each change until it matches what you have above.  At what point do the major and minor become zero?  This is the basic process to debugging a problem you do not understand.